# PHP 7 - how to catch "Cannot use object of type ... as array"?

Tags: php-7

For some weird reason, I just cannot catch that exception when it happens

here is the code, it should work but I keep getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Stuff as array in...
```

code:

```
try{
    class Stuff
    {

    }

    $stuff= new Stuff();
    $stuff["test"]=0;   <<<<<<< this should trigger the below catch 
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $myLogger->Log($e);
}
```

thanks

Comment: You need to catch `Error` (if you only want errors) or `Throwable` (if you want to catch everything) to catch errors. See also [LugiHaue's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48381661/2007837).

Comment: ok thanks, but if you dont put that as an answer then I cannot validate it :-) I'll check these out

Answer (score 1):

here is the working answer :

```
try{
    class Stuff
    {
        $test = null; 
    }

    $stuff= new Stuff();
    $stuff->test = 0;
}
catch (Throwable $e) {
    $myLogger->Log($e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. use another catch to get fatal errors

```
try{
    class Stuff
    {

    }

    $stuff= new Stuff();
    $stuff["test"]=0;   <<<<<<< this should trigger the below catch 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $myLogger->Log($e);
}  catch (Error $e) {
    // Handle error
    echo $e->getMessage(); // Call to a member function method() on string
} catch (Throwable $e) {
        // Handle error
        echo $e->getMessage(); // Call to undefined function undefinedFunctionCall()
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It always helpfull

```
try{
    class Stuff
    {
        $test = null; 

        public function getTest()
        {
            return $this->test; 
        }

        public function setTest($value)
        {
            $this->test = $value; 
        }
    }

    $stuff= new Stuff();
    $stuff->setTest(0);
    echo $stuff->getTest();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $myLogger->Log($e);
}
```

Otherwise if you want to convert an object into array then try this.

```
$stuff= new Stuff();
$stuff = (array)$stuff;
```

This will convert an object to array (By type casting)

Otherwise set directly by doing this

```
try{
    class Stuff
    {
        $test = null; 
    }

    $stuff= new Stuff();
    $stuff->test = 0;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $myLogger->Log($e);
}
```

Comment: this does not answer the question... I WANT to log the exception, not to correct it...
try my code, you'll see the exception is not catched as it should....sounds like a bug in php itself

Comment: Its a Fatal Erro and Exceptioin $e cannot get the fatal error you have to add another catch to get fatal error